# How to pass prepare for segue swift variable login username

Tags: ios, swift

In Navigation Controller, from my LoginPage, I'm trying to pass the username to my app MainViewController, and display it in a label. The username of course needs to be a variable, but successfull so far only to pass and display static text, e.g., `Arthur Dent`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "OpenPVOapp" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! MainViewController
        vc.userName = "Arthur Dent"
    }
}
// LOGIN with FACEBOOK
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
  if error != nil{
      self.lblStatus.text = error.localizedDescription
  }else if result.isCancelled{
    self.lblStatus.text = "user cancelled Login"
  }else{
  //successful Login
  // GET FACEBOOK INFO
    let params = ["fields" : "email, name"]
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    _ = graphRequest?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
      }
      if let result = result as? [String:Any]{
        guard let email = result["email"] as? String else {
          return
        }
        guard let username = result["name"] as? String else {
          return
        }
        self.lblStatus.numberOfLines = 0
        self.lblStatus.text = "CURRENT USER: " + username + "\n " + email
      }
    })
  // END GET FACEBOOK INFO
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "OpenApp", sender: nil)
  }
}
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
  self.lblStatus.text = "user logged out"
}
```

In the MainViewController:

```
var userName:String = "Anonymous"
@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userNameLabel?.text = "Current User: " + userName
}
```

Of course replacing `"Arthur Dent"` with `username` generates !Use of unresolved identifier `username`.

However, moving the `func prepare(for segue:...` block into FBSDKGraphRequest:

```
self.lblStatus.text = "CURRENT USER: " + username + "\n " + email
        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
          if segue.identifier == "Openapp" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! MainViewController
            vc.userName = username
          }
        }
```

goes and displays `Current User: Anonymous` in the MainViewController userNameLabel.

So my question is again how to configure, if possible, such a Navigation Controller `prepare(for segue:...` setup to pass the variable `username` text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
self.lblStatus.text = "CURRENT USER: " + username + "\n " + email
// just after the above line paste this
performSegue(withIdentifier: "OpenApp", sender: username)
```

Now get this username in prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "OpenPVOapp" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! MainViewController
        vc.userName = sender as? String ?? ""
    } 
}
```

Comment: Pow! Dat worked tanks! My system just needed the slight mod to your code to add self. like so: `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Openapp", sender: username)`

Comment: Now to push my luck ... how would I pass both [username, email]?

Comment: pass a dictionary like this: `["email":email,"username":username]` and then access it back like `sender as? [String:Any]`

Comment: Cool, that worked too, thanks again. Just required slight mods: `sender: [username, email]`, `vc.userInfo = (sender as? [String])!`, and `var userInfo = ["", ""]`